# URL rewrite module 2 equivalent for windows xp - IIS 5.1?

Tags: windows, iis

Is there any equivalent of http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite (URL rewrite module 2 for IIS 7) on windows XP IIS 5.1?

IIS 7 cannot be installed on Win XP. So what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to target IIS 7.+, probably the best thing is to use IIS Express, that way you get the same runtime including URL Rewrite (built-in): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx